# krsort doesn't seem to work in a particular case

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
var_dump($images);
array(2) { 
["main_product_image"]=> array(1) { ["bb2018.jpg"]=> string(63) "...018.jpg" }
["XIMAGE"]=> array(1) { ["bb2018x.jpg"]=> string(64) "...18x.jpg" } 
} 

krsort($images, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE) ;

var_dump($images);
array(2) { 
["main_product_image"]=> array(1) { ["bb2018.jpg"]=> string(63) "...018.jpg" } 
["XIMAGE"]=> array(1) { ["bb2018x.jpg"]=> string(64) "...018x.jpg" } }
```

as you can see the krsort has no effect. Why ?
Edit: before krsort() I am unset()ing some elements from the array. Could that have something to do with this ?

Comment: PHP version in use? Could you show the whole code - with unsetting part, I mean? Might be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for `SORT_FLAG_CASE` appeared in PHP only [since version 5.4.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

Without it, the keys will be reversed sorted case-sensitively, that's why `'XIMAGE'` will follow `'main_image'` (as `'X'` > `'m'`).

Note that a notice will be given by PHP if you attempt to use that flag on PHP version < 5.4 (as the constant is not defined there).

Comment: This must be it ! pretty sure it is an old php version on that machine. (not mine)

Answer (score 0):

ksort() isn't recursive.

Try using `ksort($images['main_product_image']` then `ksort($images['XIMAGE'])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = array(
  "main_product_image" =>
    array(
      "bb2018.jpg"=> "...018.jpg"
    ),
  "XIMAGE"=>
    array(
      "bb2018x.jpg" => "...18x.jpg"
    )
) ;


krsort($images, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
var_dump($images);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { 'XIMAGE' => array(1) { 'bb2018x.jpg' => string(10) "...18x.jpg" } 'main_product_image' => array(1) { 'bb2018.jpg' => string(10) "...018.jpg" } }
```

It works ok.

Comment: I tried something similar and it worked on localhost, but in my var_dump 'XIMAGE' is surrounded by [] . whats up with that ?

Comment: can you paste your $images definition ?